# Rails 4 PDFkit installation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

For my site i want to convert an HTML CSS page in a PDF.
I use the Gem "pdfkit" and follow the instructions from github and a rails cast.
But i can't get it working on rails 4
can someone help me?

I get this error

```
command failed (exitstatus=1): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 - -
```

Gem File

```
gem "pdfkit"
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
```

config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"
```

Comment: what steps you followed..? Is there any error..?

Comment: Can you post your code? I recently got it working on my app, although I do have issues with the page breaks.

Comment: i followed this rails cast [Railscast pdfkit](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) and the installation from github.[Github pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) but i think its not ready for rails 4+?

Comment: install wkhtmltopdf from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html, and remove gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"

Comment: i did, still doesn't slove the problem.. i get the same error. thanks for reply

Comment: In the rails cast they don't do anything in the controller.. what do you pass in there?

Comment: Can u show ur code Tony?